# Display data from Google Spreadsheet on Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-sheets

I would like a Google map showing worldwide location of forum users, that would be populated from a Google Spreadsheet (Google Spreadsheet will in turn be populated from Google Form)

Which should be the format for data in the spreadsheet to be translated into Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

I would put latitude and longitude information in two columns and push the spreadsheet to a Fusion Table.  You could then load the fusion table into a google map using Fusion Table Layers.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables

---

UPDATE: Google Fusion Tables and the Fusion Tables API have been discontinued as of 2019-12-03

see: https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9551050

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free tool called [GeoSheets](http://www.geosheets.com) to geocode the locations of the forum users and plot them directly on a map directly from Google Spreadsheets.  You can pass a physical address or even an IP address if you have  anonymous users.

```
=GEO_ADDRESS("1600 Pennsylvania Ave")
=GEO_IP_GEOCODE("72.14.192.0")
```

Then plotting those address on a map is as simple as:

```
=GEO_MAP(A1:A2,"forum-users")
```

Check the [docs](http://www.geosheets.com/docs) for more information on how to customize and embed the map.